# i want an answer is : A=APPLE,ANT ; B=BISCUIT ; C=CAT; D=DANCE,DOG

Tags: apex

```
List<String> lst_AllWords = new List<String>{'Apple', 'Biscuit', 'Ant', 'Cat','Dog','Dance','Eagle','Elephant'};
// list<string> lsts=new list<string>{'A','B','C','D'};
Map<String, List<String>> mp_Sorted = new Map<String, List<String>>();
List<String> lst1;
for(String lst:lst_AllWords) {
    if(lst_AllWords != null) {
        String lst2= lst.left(1);
        lst1=new List<String>();    
        lst1.add(lst);
        mp_Sorted.put(lst2,lst1);
    }
}
System.debug(mp_Sorted);
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to identify the _specific problem_. See [ask] and [help/on-topic]. Describe in the body of your question the behavior you expect and what you see instead.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to create a `Map<String, List<String>>` where key becomes first letter of the word and values becomes the List of words where first word of the word matches the key.

You did correct but you shouldn't add values directly to Map, as it overrides the previous value. Have a check if the map already contains the key then just get the value and add your new word to the list.

```
List<String> lst_AllWords = new List<String>{'Apple', 'Biscuit', 'Ant', 'Cat','Dog','Dance','Eagle','Elephant'};
// list<string> lsts=new list<string>{'A','B','C','D'};
Map<String, List<String>> mp_Sorted = new Map<String, List<String>>();
for(String lst:lst_AllWords) {
    if(lst_AllWords != null) {
        String lst2= lst.left(1);
        if(mp_Sorted.containsKey(lst2)){
            mp_Sorted.get(lst2).add(lst);
        } else {
            mp_Sorted.put(lst2,new List<String> {lst});   
        }
    }
}
System.debug(mp_Sorted);
```

> 09:38:31.13 (17113079)|USER_DEBUG|[16]|DEBUG|{A=(Apple, Ant), B=(Biscuit), C=(Cat), D=(Dog, Dance), E=(Eagle, Elephant)}